# A dictionary that stores nothing after goes out from the wrapper

Tags: python, function, oop, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to store in PLUGINS dictionary, the addresses of the functions decorated
The problem is that inside the wrapper everything looks like to go good, storing the addresses then, after it gets out they disappear from the PLUGINS, why is it? and why when I print say_hello('Addam') appears two '{}'

(I know that when I decorate a function with a wrapper I'm changing the decorated function address by the wrapper direction)

```
PLUGINS = dict()

def register(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        
        print('hello', func.__name__) #hello say_hello
        
        """Register a function as a plug-in"""
        PLUGINS[func.__name__] = func
        print(PLUGINS) #{'say_hello': <function say_hello at 0x7f9e59915090>}
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    
    print(PLUGINS) #{} (printed twice)
    
    return wrapper

@register
def say_hello(name):
    return f"Hello {name}"

@register
def be_awesome(name):
    return f"Yo {name}, together we are the awesomest!"



print(say_hello('Addam'))
print(PLUGINS) #{}
```

Comment: You should be storing your functions in the `PLUGINS` dict as part of decorating them. You should move the line `PLUGINS[func.__name__] = func` up to be the first line in the `register()` function. (btw you never mention why you need the dict).

Comment: Add another argument to `print(PLUGINS)` so you know which one you're seeing, like `print('in wrapper', PLUGINS)`

Comment: `wrapper()` isn't called until you call the decorated function. So `say_hello` is added to the dictionary when you call `say_hello('Addam')`. `be_awesome` isn't added because you never call it.

Answer (score 0):

first I think that you have an error in your last line : print(PLUGINS) #{}. Your plugins are already properly registered at this point and you should see the expected, two registered functions. Another point is the global variable PLUGINS, which would be frown upon from some developers.

I would propose the following solution, which has the advantage that everything is properly encapsulated in a class:

```
from pprint import pp


class register:
    PLUGINS = {}

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.func_name = func.__name__

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.PLUGINS[self.func_name] = self.func
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def print_all_regs(cls):
        pp(cls.PLUGINS)


@register
def say_hello( name ):
    return f"Hello {name}"

# RESULT:
# -------   
# Hello Addam
# Yo Addam, together we are the awesomest!
#{'say_hello': <function say_hello at 0x0000000000485160>,
# 'be_awesome': <function be_awesome at 0x000000000B59AC10>}
```

Good luck :)